# Add grid label to QGIS layout from shapefile

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mgrs

I have a GRID shapefile with calculated MGRS coordinates. I am trying to display them in the QGIS print layout and place them on the map edges. It will look similar to standard QGIS grid creation. Is it possible to get the shapefile table values from Layout Custom Expression?

[image: Image2]

A better example of what I am trying to achieve. The blue letters are the missing information.
I would like to add 10k labels to my grid. I already have all the information needed in the SHP attribute table. All I really need is to find a way to intersect the QGIS Layout grid with shapefile polygons.
[image]
I feel that a custom QGIS layout with proper expression could do that, but I don't have enough experience with it.

Comment: What keeps you from using the [`grid`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html?highlight=layout#guides-and-grid) included in the layout manager?

Comment: MGRS is UTM zone-dependent and it's a combination of letters and numbers eg the coordinate that I need to display is 14RPU0240. Also in the single map, I can have 4 different UTM EPSG zones. To avoid dynamic recalculating it in a grid layout, I usually use my MGRS shapefiles for 1k, 10k and 100k scale maps. If I have some way to intersect the layout grid with my mgrs polygons I could easily get valid numbers.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way to calculate MGRS coordinates in the QGIS layout for multiple zones.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System